# Kotlin get declared member property value

Tags: kotlin, reflection

What is the equivalent code of [`Class#getDeclaredField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-) in Kotlin? I'm looking for a pure Kotlin implementation... a reflection perhaps?

```
class Test {
    public static final String TEST = "Hello";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
            Test.class.getDeclaredField("TEST").get(Test.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, add this dependency to avoid runtime error

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.50</version>
</dependency>
```

then:

```
val member = Test::class.members.find { it.name=="TEST" }
println(member)
println(member.call(Test())
```

output:

```
val generic.Test.TEST: kotlin.String
Hello
```

member type is **Kcallable<*>?**

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/index.html

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer :)  

Just an addition, [`KClass#members`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/members.html) returns the `Collection` of all the class members including those functions and properties inherited from superclasses, if one would want just the declared properties of the class; use [`KClass#declaredMemberProperties`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/declared-member-properties.html).  

Example:  

`val member = Test::class.declaredMemberProperties.find { it.name == "TEST" }?.call()`