# How to instantiate model class from nested classes with kotlin reflection

Tags: android, kotlin

Can't seem to get my head around the reflection documentation for Kotlin.

I have a bunch of nested classes which implement an interface so they all have the same methods and properties. I want to show each of these class in a RecyclerView. I'm almost there but I can't get the information from my classes to build my model class which will be used in the RecyclerAdapter.

I got my list of nested classes, but I can't figure out how to access to properties so i can instantiate a model.

This is my interface:

```
interface SquibCommand {
    val title: String
    val description: String
    fun setParams(commandParams: CommandParams)
    fun execute()
}
```

Then I can get a Collection of all the nested classes like this:

```
val commandClass = AllCommands::class
val commandList = commandClass.nestedClasses
Log.d("Commands", "Your command collection is " + commandList)
```

Then I need to build a model from each command that can be used to populate the fields in my adapter view. Something like:

```
commandModels = ArrayList<CommandModel>
commandList.forEach {
   val cmd: CommandModel
   cmd.title = it.title 
   cmd.description = it.description 
   commandModels.add(cmd)
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the actual value of the title and description properties from each class, rather than just the name of the property.

EDIT:

So I can access the properties of any single class by doing:

```
    val myOtherClass = AllCommands.TimerCommand::class.members.find {it.name == "title"}
    Log.d("BrowseCommands", "Your commands list is " + myOtherClass!!.call(AllCommands.TimerCommand()))
```

but as I have to access all the nested classes from a collection, I can't figure out what to pass to the Call... it should surely be something like:

```
    val myClass = commandList.elementAt(0)
    Log.d("BrowseCommands", "Your commands list is " + myClass.members.find {it.name == "title"}?.call(myClass()))
```

But this doesn't work. How do I instantiate the class when it is from within the commandList collection?

Comment: How can you have values of `title` and `description` if you don't have instances of these classes? What would you actually be displaying?

Comment: The properties are set in each class: i.e. override val title: String = "My Unique Title"

Comment: Default expressions cannot be retrieved because of the reason given here: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-reflection-and-default-values/2254 The implementation of these properties may effectively be constants, but they exist as expressions in byte code.

Comment: That is for function parameters, not class properties. A property is retrived in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58351219/kotlin-get-declared-member-property-value but this is for a single class, where as I have a Collection of nested class so nothing I pass to the call() seems to work.

Comment: Yes, but I think the same reasoning applies. The code after `=` in a property initializer is an expression, not a constant value. The expression is evaluated and the result assigned to a backing field when an instance of the class is initialized. Property initializers are basically shorthand for `init` blocks, which are blocks of code run as part of the object construction at initialization time.

Comment: Ok, but they still got it working in the thread I shared. It's the same thing isn't it?

Comment: No, because they create an instance of the class by calling the constructor `Test()` and then read values from that instance. You could do the same thing if none of your inner classes are abstract and they all have empty constructors. Then you could create instances via reflection.

Comment: Ah, I see. I got it working I retrieve a single one of the nested class, but can't do it for a collection of nested class.Have edited my question to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it if all of the nested classes you care about have empty constructors. You have to instantiate an instance to be able to read values from the properties, because the expression in your property initialization is not accessible by reflection.

```
val commandModels = commandList.mapNotNull { kClass ->
    val instance = kClass.constructors.firstOrNull { it.parameters.isEmpty() }
        ?.call() as SquibCommand?
    instance?.let { CommandModel(it.title, it.description) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks will give this a go and vote if works. Just need to wrap my head around some of the unfamiliar terms and syntax ( my brain is still unable to cope with Lambas lol).